# Why api works fine locally but remotely shows unsatisfied dependency?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jar, amazon-ses

I have a rest api in Spring Framework with Java, it works with amazon aws services, using the "aws-java-sdk-1.5.0.jar" file, working very well. But, I have to implement Amazon SES and that version of that jar doesn't support it, for that reason I downloaded a most recent version "aws-java-sdk-1.11.269.jar", I replaced it and deleted the previous version, and rebuild the project. It works fine again but only locally. Remotely the WAR file cannot be deployed, It shows an error about Unsatisfied dependency exception, but remember locally deploys and works fine. Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

```
13-Sep-2019 20:43:16.892 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
13-Sep-2019 20:43:16.909 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
13-Sep-2019 20:43:19.363 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]


 org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'settingsRestFacade': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'fileStorageServices'; nested exception is 

 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fileStorageServices' defined in com.desafioguerreros.SpringConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is 

 org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.desafioguerreros.infrastructure.storage.FileStorageServices]: Factory method 'fileStorageServices' threw exception; nested exception is 

 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<init>(Ljavax/net/ssl/SSLContext;Ljavax/net/ssl/HostnameVerifier;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:587)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:373)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1348)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:578)

...
```

Comment: Make sure, old jar is not on your local classpath!

Comment: @Kris I deleted, another suggestion?

Comment: Can you  note the version of the JRE that you have present locally and in the remote evironment.

Comment: To see where in the classpath the http client is being loaded on your local deployment, add this to a log statement ```org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()```  This should give you a hint as to whether the jar is indeed available in the remote deployment.

Comment: @0xadecimal practically the same version 1.8.0_181 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode), VS 1.8.0_191 Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)